# Resize dynamic DIV with imgs/slider - max width not functioning as planned

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am finishing up the new homepage and adjusting the tweaks for responsiveness. At the moment the navigation with a burger and logo resizing is working fine.

Homepage: http://www.showstyle.lu/

When you arrive at the slider area (4 images, 2 which are sliders) I tried various methods on the media query < 1199px such as creating "display: blocks;" so that they would at least appear below one another but it isn't aesthethic at all.

Quite frankly I would not mind at all if 4 portions would just dynamically resize until maybe 300px where I would simply add 4 basic flat images for the smallest smartphones - for tablets at least a resize function would look better.

So: I surrounded the 4 divs in a #v2_slider_mob and gave it the same resizing attributed I have on other portions of the website:

```
#v2_slider_mob {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

Here is the code for the 4 divs:

```
#v2_selline1 {
  display: block !important;
  width: 100%; 
  height: 300px; 
}

#v2_selbox1 {
  float: left;
  width: 750px;
  height: 100%;
}

#v2_selbox2 {  
  float: left;
  width: 375px;
  height: 100%;

}
#v2_selline2 {
  display: block !important;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px; 
}

#v2_selbox3 {
  float: left;
  width: 562px;
  height: 100%;  
}

#v2_selbox4 {
  float: left;
  width: 562px;
  height: 100%;  
}
```

At the moment the images are still just ligning up below one another instead of the whole div reducing in size, any ideas how to solve this?

If I can solve this I can then use the same principle for other portions of the homepage like the footer/bottom half that need to be well resized on smaller screens too :)

Answer (score 0):

All css values in % are related to the first parent with a specified position.
Add position relative to the parent element you want and it will work as expect.

Answer (score 0):

you need to make this change

```
#v2_selbox1 {
float: left;
max-width: 750px;
height: 100%;
```

}

I have tested it

also edit this to remove the white space because of the height:300

```
 #v2_selline1 {
display: block !important;
width: 100%;
max-height: 300px;
```

}

Comment: The solution works, the max-width was on the parent element of each individual div helped, I think I can definitely clean up some of the css as there is still a lot of redundancy but this helped quite a bit, thanks all.